# MVVM WPF binding broken with ItemContainerStyle on ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, binding

When I apply an ItemContainerStyle to my ListView (GridView),the ItemSource binding displays the object name instead of the object values. Essentially, the binding no longer works when I apply a container style. I don't see why this would be the case as I still retain the DisplayMemeberBinding to properties on the object.

Here is example code:

Model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Randy Orton";
    public int Age { get; set; } = 26;
    public bool Employed { get; set; } = true;

    public Person(string name, int age, bool employed)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Employed = Employed;
    }

    public Person()
    {
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person> { new Person(), new 
        Person(), new Person() };
    }
```

View:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
    <Style x:Key="listviewitemStyle"
           TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightTextBrushKey"
                 Color="Black" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightBrushKey"
                 Color="#7d7d7d" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightMouseOverBrushKey"
                 Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource HighlightBrushKey}, Path=Color}"
                 Opacity="0.3" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="disabledTextBrushKey"
                             Color="#303030" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="disabledBrushKey"
                             Color="#595959" />
        </Style.Resources>

        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                         Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightMouseOverBrushKey}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HighlightTextBrushKey}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBrushKey}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HighlightTextBrushKey}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource disabledBrushKey}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource disabledTextBrushKey}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView
        ItemsSource="{Binding People, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource listviewitemStyle}">

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Employed" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Employed, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: There is a plain `<ContentPresenter />` in your ListViewItem ControlTemplate. It knows nothing about a DisplayMemberBinding. It's also unclear how you expect the GridView to work when you replace the ControlTemplate. You don't have columns anymore, do you?

Comment: I still have columns. This code works exactly as I want and expect it to if you remove  the ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: There are no columns at the indiviual items, only a single text with what a ContentPresenter does by default, i.e. the result of Person.ToString().

Comment: Could you give me a code example of how I could fix this please?

Comment: Take a look at [ListView Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates) to see that there is a GridViewRowPresenter instead of a ContentPresenter.

Comment: Gracing me with a code answer would be super cool though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix, all one has to do is change the `ContentPresenter` to a `GridViewRowPresenter` inside the ControlTemplate